# Is there a bug in "zgrep -H"?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

Just tried grep and zgrep on following test file:

```
[user@host:~]$ cat /tmp/test
2015-07-16 14:01:24 aaaa
2015-07-16 14:02:57 bbbb
```

I also need the file-name printed, so I've added the `-H` switch and stepped on the following problem:

```
[user@host:~]$ grep aaaa -A1 -H /tmp/test
/tmp/test:2015-07-16 14:01:24 aaaa
/tmp/test-2015-07-16 14:02:57 bbbb
[user@host:~]$ zgrep aaaa -A1 -H /tmp/test
/tmp/test:2015-07-16 14:01:24 aaaa
/tmp/test:02:57 bbbb
[user@host:~]$ zgrep aaaa -A1 /tmp/test -H
/tmp/test:2015-07-16 14:01:24 aaaa
/tmp/test:2015-07-16 14:02:57 bbbb
```

E.g. depending on POSITION of `-H` switch in the command-line - the behavior is different for me and the issue always reproduces :(

One more test:

```
[user@host:~]$ gzip /tmp/test
[user@host:~]$ zgrep aaaa -A1 -H /tmp/test.gz
/tmp/test.gz:2015-07-16 14:01:24 aaaa
/tmp/test.gz:02:57 bbbb
[user@host:~]$ zgrep aaaa -A1 /tmp/test.gz -H
/tmp/test.gz:2015-07-16 14:01:24 aaaa
/tmp/test.gz:2015-07-16 14:02:57 bbbb
```

Here's the outline of which zgrep I'm using:

```
[user@host:~]$ ls -l `which zgrep`
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root 3121 Jan 14  2010 /usr/bin/zgrep*
[user@host:~]$ head `which zgrep`
#!/bin/sh

# zgrep -- a wrapper around a grep program that decompresses files as needed
# Adapted from a version sent by Charles Levert <charles@comm.polymtl.ca>

# Copyright (C) 1998, 2001, 2002 Free Software Foundation
# Copyright (C) 1993 Jean-loup Gailly

# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
```

Any clue of if it's a known bug or am I doing something wrong?
Any alternatives? (like to invoke regular grep and then somehow prepend it with file-name without complex temporary files or overhead)

**Update** (thanks to dimo414's answer):

Tried to upgrade a bit and faced even more subtle problems (so it looks like only latest or specific versions are working properly):

```
[user@rhel66:~]$ grep --version|head -1
GNU grep 2.6.3
[user@rhel66:~]$ zgrep --version|head -1
zgrep (gzip) 1.3.12
[user@rhel66:~]$ grep aaaa -A1 -H /tmp/test
/tmp/test:2015-07-16 14:01:24 aaaa
/tmp/test-2015-07-16 14:02:57 bbbb
[user@rhel66:~]$ zgrep aaaa -A1 -H /tmp/test
gzip: -A1.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: -H.gz: No such file or directory
/tmp/test:2015-07-16 14:01:24 aaaa
[user@rhel66:~]$ zgrep aaaa -A1 /tmp/test -H
gzip: -A1.gz: No such file or directory
/tmp/test:2015-07-16 14:01:24 aaaa
gzip: -H.gz: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What zgrep version? I remember the old one was unusable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see the error you describe:

```
$ grep aaaa -A1 -H /tmp/test
/tmp/test:2015-07-16 14:01:24 aaaa
/tmp/test-2015-07-16 14:02:57 bbbb

$ zgrep aaaa -A1 -H /tmp/test
/tmp/test:2015-07-16 14:01:24 aaaa
/tmp/test:2015-07-16 14:02:57 bbbb

$ zgrep aaaa -A1 /tmp/test -H
/tmp/test:2015-07-16 14:01:24 aaaa
/tmp/test:2015-07-16 14:02:57 bbbb
```

This is likely a known and fixed bug, and you're running an old version of `grep` and/or `zgrep`.  The output of `zgrep --version` would be helpful, on my machine it's:

```
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.16
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others, see <http://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.

$ zgrep --version
zgrep (gzip) 1.6
Copyright (C) 2010-2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software.  You may redistribute copies of it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Jean-loup Gailly.
```

Comment: Thank You, that's old legacy system. I'll look into what was fixed exactly :) My versions are `grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1`, `gzip 1.3.5` and `zgrep` doesn't accept `--version` arg (same for `--help` and `-v`), I wasn't aware they've added the `--version` support in the newer versions, so thank You again!

Comment: I've updated my question with details after switching from RHEL5.6 to CentOS6.6 - looks like only latest (or some specific) versions are working properly, so I'll try to use the ones You've quoted in the answer :)